# При выполнении loadState в JqGrid, теряются данные в navGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

При сохранении состояния таблицы при помощи

```
     $.jgrid.saveState("jqGrid");
```

, а затем его загрузки

```
     $.jgrid.loadState("jqGrid");
```

, теряются данные из панели навигации navGrid, если таковые есть...

До $.jgrid.loadState("jqGrid") :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После $.jgrid.loadState("jqGrid") :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Вероятней всего, вы забыли вставить параметр  `"storeNavOptions : true"` в грид.

```
...jqGrid ({
...
storeNavOptions : true
...
});
```